# How to prove the following: Every set is Turing reducible to itself

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

Question:
Prove the following:  Every set is Turing reducible to itself.

If anyone can provide a solution that would be great, I've just been introduced to computation theory so be as descriptive as you like for my sake if not strictly for the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Informally, $A$ is Turing reducible to $B$ if you can figure out what $A$ is by asking questions to $B$.

A bit more formally, $A$ is Turing reducible to $B$ if there's some algorithm you can use to figure out whether a number is in $A$ by asking questions about whether or not various numbers are in $B$. For example, an instance of a Turing reduction between $A$ and $B$ might look like the following:

- I want to figure out whether $3$ is in $A$.
- I ask $B$, "Is $17$ in you?"
- $B$ says **yes**.
- I now say, "Okay, based on that answer I now want to ask: is $42$ in you?"
- $B$ says **no**.
- I say, "Great! Now I know that $3$ **is** in $A$.

So, you're trying to do the following: given some arbitrary set $A$ and an arbitrary number $n$, **find a way to figure out whether $n$ is in $A$ by "querying" $A$.** (*HINT*: don't overthink this ...)

---

Incidentally, Turing reductions don't have to be efficient, or non-stupid, or anything else nice; they just have to *work*. For example, in the problem you're trying to solve, there is a "best" Turing reduction; but we could *also* modify that reduction to pointlessly ask "Is $17$ in $A$?" at the end for absolutely no reason, and simply ignore that extra information.

Comment: "Turing reductions don't have to be non-stupid" -- wise words, indeed!